# How to decode mp3 to pcm using lame?

Tags: c++, pcm, lame

I'm looking for an example of how to decode mp3 to pcm using c++

I found an example that shows how to encode! And it works fine for me!

How about decode?

Thanks!!!

Encoding function:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lame/lame.h>

int main(void)
{
    int read, write;

    FILE *pcm = fopen("file.pcm", "rb");
    FILE *mp3 = fopen("file.mp3", "wb");

    const int PCM_SIZE = 8192;
    const int MP3_SIZE = 8192;

    short int pcm_buffer[PCM_SIZE*2];
    unsigned char mp3_buffer[MP3_SIZE];

    lame_t lame = lame_init();
    lame_set_in_samplerate(lame, 44100);
    lame_set_VBR(lame, vbr_default);
    lame_init_params(lame);

    do {
        read = fread(pcm_buffer, 2*sizeof(short int), PCM_SIZE, pcm);
        if (read == 0)
            write = lame_encode_flush(lame, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
        else
            write = lame_encode_buffer_interleaved(lame, pcm_buffer, read, mp3_buffer, MP3_SIZE);
        fwrite(mp3_buffer, write, 1, mp3);
    } while (read != 0);

    lame_close(lame);
    fclose(mp3);
    fclose(pcm);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: LAME only encodes.  You could try [here](https://www.mpg123.de/api/).

Comment: PS: You're playing a bit fast and loose with `MP3_SIZE` there.

Comment: Really @PaulSanders? I didn't know! Let me try mpg123 then